# mongo: Lower index bound of date query set to true after adding data

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem where a mongo query is evaluated differently after adding new data
to the DB.
Basically, I try to query for entries in a given date range.

Before the data is added, the index bounds are set to the values given by the query as expected and `isMultiKey = false`:

```
> db.tf.find( { "transforms.header.stamp": { $lt: new Date(1396512603500), $gte: new Date(1396512602000) } } ).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transforms.header.stamp_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 49,
    "nscannedObjects" : 49,
    "nscanned" : 49,
    ....
    "millis" : 3,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "transforms.header.stamp" : [
            [
                ISODate("2014-04-03T08:10:02Z"),
                ISODate("2014-04-03T08:10:03.500Z")
            ]
        ]
    }
    ....
}
```

After the data is added, the lower index bound is set to `true` so that the whole document up to the upper bound is scanned and `isMultiKey = true`:

```
> db.tf.find( { "transforms.header.stamp": { $lt: new Date(1396512603500), $gte: new Date(1396512602000) } } ).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transforms.header.stamp_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 49,
    "nscannedObjects" : 20489,
    "nscanned" : 20489,
    ....
    "millis" : 645,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "transforms.header.stamp" : [
             [
                 true,
                 ISODate("2014-04-03T08:10:03.500Z")
             ]
        ]
    }
    ....
}
```

As far as I understand, `multiKey = true` means that the index was build over
array values. But "transform.header.stamp" does not contain any array values:

```
> db.tf.find( { "transforms.header.stamp": { $type: 4 } } ).count()
0
```

Entries with date type are found as expected:

```
> db.tf.find( { "transforms.header.stamp": { $type: 9 } } ).count()
554672
```

A query for entries with time-stamp type yields in an error (why?):

```
> db.tf.find( { "transforms.header.stamp": { $type: 17 } } ).count()
Mon Dec 22 11:53:19 uncaught exception: count failed: {
    "code" : 13111,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "13111 wrong type for field () 17 != 9"
}
```

Why is the lower bound set to `true` and
why is `multiKey = true` after adding new data?
There must be something wrong with the added data but
I wasn't able to figure it out (it's a JSON dump of 5GB).

**EDIT**: Using $elemMatch it works again:

```
> db.tf.find( { "transforms.header.stamp": { $elemMatch: { $lt: new Date(1396512603500), $gte: new Date(1396512602000) } } } ).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transforms.header.stamp_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 49,
    "nscanned" : 49,
    ....
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "transforms.header.stamp" : [
            [
                ISODate("2014-04-03T08:10:02Z"),
                ISODate("2014-04-03T08:10:03.500Z")
            ]
        ]
    }
    ....
}
```

So it really looks like there are array values. How can I query for them?

Comment: Are there any values for `transforms.header.stamp` that are objects? `db.tf.find({ "transforms.header.stamp" : { "$type" : 3 } })`? Also try querying for all documents that have a type for the field that is NOT a timestamp: `db.tf.find({ "transforms.header.stamp" : { "$not" : { "$type" : 4 } } })`

Comment: In fact there were some records where this value was undefined. I removed them so that `db.tf.find({ "transforms.header.stamp" : { "$not" : { "$type" : 4 } } }) = 0`. But the problem remains, unfortunately